# Memset memory allocation

Tags: c, memset

given the following code in C:

```
char str[] = "";

size_t size = strlen(str) + 1;

char *actual = memset(malloc(size), '@', size);
```

After I run this, actual = "@"  .

If malloc assigns only 1 byte for actual variable,

how can it initialize it with '@' , which requires 2 bytes(because of the null char)?

Thanx

I tried to run the code and I thought it would raise an error but it didn't.

Answer (score 0):

> After I run this, actual = "@" .

The post contains no support for this assertion. Possibly you added `printf("%s\n", actual);` in the code, and the program printed “@”. That does not mean the `memset` put a null byte after the `'@'`.

`char *actual = memset(malloc(size), '@', size);` allocates one byte and sets it to `'@'`. It does not control what value appears the byte after that or even that there is any memory mapped at that address.

It is possible there is a byte in memory after the `'@'` that contains the value zero, and that `printf` looked at the memory where `actual` points and found the `'@'` and the null byte and printed the `'@'`. It is even likely this is the case because this probably was the only code in your program, so nothing had used much memory yet, so there was a zero in memory after the `'@'` simply because it had been initialized to zero by the operating system and not changed by your program. However, this is not behavior you can rely on. The byte after the `'@'` could contain a different value, and `printf` would behave differently.

Additionally, because the behavior in this situation is not defined by the C standard, optimization by the compiler could transform your program in ways you may find surprising. For example, it would be conforming to the C standard for the compiler to determine the behavior is not defined, so that all of the code in your program could be eliminated.

Comment: memset can invoke UB if malloc fails too

Comment: @gulpr: That is not what the question is about, so it is not relevant. The question is about how `memset` behaves and, apparently, why OP observed behavior as if the string `"@"` were at `actual`. The use of `malloc` is incidental as part of an artificial code sequence used for testing and asking on Stack Overflow, not for production code. Stack Overflow is not a tutorial service, and questions should not always be answered by teaching the asker about how to write complete code. A focus on the specific question asked is appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

This code invokes ***U***ndefined ***B***ehaviour as `malloc` may fail.

If it does not the rest of the code shown is OK as you do not use `actual` as a *C string*. But this pointer references ***one*** element `char` array witch ***can't*** hold the `"@"` string.

If you try to use it as a *C string* then you will invoke another `UB`

> how can it initialize it with '@' , which requires 2 bytes(because of
> the null char)?

You mean with **`"@"`** - you can't as you do not have enough space. Also, `memset` does not add magically 0 at the end of the set area.

if you want to use `memset` to create a C string (UB also possible if malloc fails)

```
int main(void)
{
    char str[] = "";

    size_t size = strlen(str) + 2;

    char *actual;
    memset((actual = memset(malloc(size), '@', size)) + 1, 0, size -1);
    printf("\"%s\"\n", actual);
}
```

Comment: Re “This code invokes **U**ndefined **B**ehaviour as `malloc` may fail”: There may be undefined behavior. That is different from there is undefined behavior. And this possibility is not what OP is encountering.